# Eclipse/STS Java editor background color forces white

Tags: eclipse

I'm new to STS (coming from IntelliJ). I wanted a dark theme, so I installed Eclipse Color Themes plugin and applied a theme (Obsidian). It looks great with JSP, XML, HTML, JavaScript, properties files... etc.

But, when I open up a Java file I get a white background. Every other color is correctly changed (and largely unreadable on a white background).

It looks like this (cropped screenshot): https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIJGl.png

The dark color on the left is defined in General --> Editors --> Text Editors: Background color

Searching "background" in the preferences, I cannot find any other place where background colors are defined for Java files.

I'm using Spring Tool Suite version 3.3.0.RELEASE. I also opened Eclipse Juno and it does the same thing.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? It started randomly and it's driving me nuts!

Comment: I did not. I spent a couple hours trying to figure it out through settings and plugins and even tried to revert back to the original ugly state without any theme. I recall Eclipse seemed hosed at that point and it was better just to delete my workspace and start over. After getting things up again, I skipped the themes and stayed ugly. On the plus side, I'm back with IntelliJ now so I don't have to deal with that anymore.

Comment: Thanks for responding. After exhausting my other options, I started removing a bunch of plugins (basically all that weren't core for Eclipse functionality). It seems (for me) that the Aptana Plugin played at least a partial role because the problem was fixed when I removed it. Can't say for sure that it was 100% responsible, but for any other desperate sole reading, it's a good place to start.

Answer (score 4):

Please  go to Help->Eclipse market place

and in the Find bar, search for Color.

You'll be getting "Eclipse Color Theme by NodeEclipse...."

Click install button in under this search result.

Just follow install procedure and complete installation.

Now go to Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Color Theme.

There you can find different themes for your STS....

All The Best

Answer (score 0):

That`s what Aptana Plugin do. To fix This you should go to Window -> Preferences -> Aptana -> Themes and set check box called (Applay to all (non Studio) editors) in down right corner.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with Mac, and fixed it simply by disabling the ANSI Console inside the STS; it marked with (A) label on the top right corner at the console.

[image]